# Group products - Shopify

Tags: magento, shopify, liquid

By default Shopify do not have group products like Magento, where you can add simple products to a main product. Therefor I have made it myself on my store. I have tagged all simple product with a tag called 'free_product' and the main products with a tag called 'main'

Product 1: https://sengefabrikken-test.myshopify.com/products/tromso-elevation-lysegra-180x200-cm?_pos=6&_psq=troms%C3%B8%20elevation%20%28lysegr%C3%A5&_ss=e&_v=1.0

Product 2: https://sengefabrikken-test.myshopify.com/products/lyngdal-180x200-cm?_pos=2&_psq=lyngdal%20-%20180&_ss=e&_v=1.0

Right now I have a problem with the cart page. Right now I have made it so the simple products quantity follow the main quantity. However this is a problem if you EX buy to different products with different quantities as you can see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sylmgtz2lux4vpy/group_products.jpg?dl=0

As shown in the link above then the quantites on all the simple product is 2 though one of the main products quantity is 1.

Right now I have thought about to hide the function where you can change the quantity on the cart page, so the customers only have the option to set quantity on the product page, as I then can delete the code on the cart page that tells simple products quantity should follow the main product quantity.

Any others ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes I think the best thing is to disable the ability to update the quantity of the `free_product` products. You could even make sure that the number of `free_product` products is the right quantity for the number of `main` products in the cart form.

However a user could still alter the code with dev tools, etc, so it's not completely fool proof.

You can also use things like [line item properties](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/line_item#line_item-properties) to help you associate which `main` products the `free_product`s belong to.